# Наращивание функционала asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Только начал изучать asp.net mvc. Начал с баз данных, научился выгружать данный из бд, изменять, создавать, удалять)
Теперь суть в том, что я хочу увеличить функционал, т.е. добавить свой класс с необходимыми методами, полями и тд. Вопрос следующего, в какую "папку" добавлять этот класс. Как к нему обращаться. И как из него обращаться к элементам созданным на View части?

Comment: Зависит от назначения класса. Модели - в одну папку, ВьюМодели - в другую, класс бизнес-логики - в третью. И т. д.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, понял. К примеру, у меня есть поле в котором я выбираю из DropList данные. Как сделать что бы при выборе данные добавлялись в другое поле?

Comment: Это уже совсем другой вопрос. Попробуйте пробежать какой нибудь курс по asp.net, многое встанет на свои места

Comment: @Valera JavaScript'ом.

Comment: @tym32167, было бы не плохо. Но все что я нахожу это не понятно для меня) какой нибудь наглядный пример обработки события выбора из дроплиста я не смог найти. Есть варианты через кнопку, но это как переделать я не понимаю

Comment: Не знаю актуально ли, но раньше была книжка по asp.net mvc от автора - Стивена Сандерсона, там был пример с целым интернет магазином, если найдете, пробегитесь по ней.